# Any way to separate unit tests from integration tests in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, continuous-integration, mstest, integration-testing

I have a project full of tests, unit and integration alike.  Integration tests require that a pretty large database be present, so it's difficult to make it a part of the build process simply because of the time that it takes to re-initialize the database.

Is there a way to somehow separate unit tests from integration tests and have the build server just run the unit tests?

I see that there is an Ordered Unit test in VS2008, which allows you to pick and choose tests, but I can't make it just execute alone, without all the others.  Is there a trick that I am missing?

Or perhaps I could adorn the unit tests with an attribute?  What are some of the approaches people are using?

P.S. I know I could use mocking for integration tests (just to make them go faster) but then it wouldn't be a true integration test.

Comment: If you ever upgrade to 2010 or beyond, you can use the TestCategory attribute to mark unit test and integration tests differently and then run only the ones you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is have separate projects and then you can run tests against each assembly independently.

Comment: Seems like an overkill.  You should be able to declaratively state which tests are unit tests and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create customized lists of tests.  Double-click on the .vsmdi file in "Solution Items" to get to the lists of tests for your solution.